# approach for to delete the extent report html file before executing feature file?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, bdd, selenium-extent-report

```
Feature: Capability(Model) module feature

Scenario: User is Logged In
    Given Accelare url is launched
    When User Enters valid username "yashodeep.patil@nitorinfotech.com" and password "Workfit2511#"
    Then Verify if App Testing Accelare is opened
    And Click on verify app testing page

Scenario: Create a new model
    Given user navigated to new model form
    When User click on new model link
    Then User is able to see the model in dropdown model
  And Click on verify app testing page


Scenario: Import the model
    Given User navigate to the model import window
    When user click on design button
    Then user is able to upload the model
    And Click on verify app testing page

Scenario: Export the model  
    Given User navigate to the model export window
    When user click on Export button
    Then user is able to export the model
    And Click on verify app testing page
```

I want to delete the HTML report before executing the feature file because what happened The HTML report file is overwriting the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the before annotation to delete the file

If you want to delete the HTML file before each feature file execution, then add some annotation to your feature file and the use the same annotation in your Before method as below

**Feature:**

```
@feature1
Feature: Capability(Model) module feature

Scenario: User is Logged In
```

In Before hooks, you can perform the HTML Report delete action.

```
@Before("@feature1")
public void beforeFeature() {
  // HTML Delete Actions
}
```

Comment: @After("@feature1")
  public static void closebrowser()
  {
   
   Testfactory.driver.close();
  }

getting this error message Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'